# How i can switch between icons with javascript when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I switch between icons with javascript when clicked?

```js
function mode() {
  var moon = document.getElementById("mode");
  moon.src = "https://img.icons8.com/sf-black-filled/35/fffffe/moon-symbol.png";
  moon.id = "lightmode";
  moon.onclick = lightmode();
}

function lightmode() {
  var sun = document.getElementById("lightmode");
  sun.src = "https://img.icons8.com/sf-black-filled/34/000000/sun.png";
  sun.onclick = mode();
}
```

```css
body { background-color:grey }
```

```html
<div class="nav-icons">
  <img id="mode" class="moon" onclick="mode()" src="https://img.icons8.com/sf-black-filled/35/fffffe/moon-symbol.png">
  <img id="notification" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/34/fffffe/notification-center.png" alt="" srcset="">
</div>
```

Comment: `moon.onclick = lightmode();` - you are _calling_ the function `lightmode` here at this point - which is most likely not what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up event listeners in an incorrect manner

Here is a toggle using classes and data attributes

```js
const srcs = {
  "dark": "https://img.icons8.com/sf-black-filled/35/fffffe/moon-symbol.png",
  "light": "https://img.icons8.com/sf-black-filled/34/000000/sun.png"
};
const modeToggle = document.getElementById("modeToggle");
modeToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let mode = this.dataset.mode;
  mode = mode === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"; // toggle
  this.src = srcs[mode]; // image
  this.dataset.mode = mode; // save in element
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark",mode==="dark"); // toggle page too
})
document.body.classList.toggle("dark",modeToggle.dataset.mode==="dark"); // initialise the page, possibly from localStorage
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey
}

body.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-icons">
  <img id="modeToggle" data-mode="light" src="https://img.icons8.com/sf-black-filled/34/000000/sun.png">
  <img id="notification" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/34/fffffe/notification-center.png" alt="" srcset="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may solve your problem, please use proper names for your functions, e.g instead of mode() use changeMode() as a name

javascript:

```
let isChanged = false;
let mode = document.querySelector('#mode');

function changeMode(){
  isChanged = !isChanged;
  if(isChanged) {
    mode.src = "https://img.icon8.com/sf-black-filled/35/ffffffe/moon-symbol.png"
  } else {
    mode.src = "https://img.icon8.com/sf-black-filled/34/000000/sun.png"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggling between two different images/icons/styles is very simple in Javascript. You could, for instance, create a simple Object literal with name/value pairs for both icons as per the following. A simple `ternary` operator determines what the src should be based upon the current src

```js
document.querySelector('.nav-icons > img.sunmoon').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  let icons={
    sun:'https://img.icons8.com/sf-black-filled/34/000000/sun.png',
    moon:'https://img.icons8.com/sf-black-filled/35/fffffe/moon-symbol.png'
  };
  this.src = this.src==icons.moon ? icons.sun : icons.moon;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-icons">
  <img class="sunmoon" src="https://img.icons8.com/sf-black-filled/35/fffffe/moon-symbol.png" />
  <img id="notification" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/34/fffffe/notification-center.png" alt="" srcset="" />
</div>
```